# converting lots (100+) of analogue audio sources to RTP/UDP/'IP packets'?

Tags: audio, analog

I was 50/50 posting this here or another board.. hopefully it's in context and maybe I can get some help!

Basically I have a scenario where I'll have just over 100 analogue audio sources (50 in and 50 out) from 50 devices. I'll need to differentiate between the sources at a server to process each device individually. This is a communications thing, and has nothing to do with music.

Now.. I could invest in a huge mixer that converts from analogue to digital (ADC). But we're getting into big figures!

I've got a VoIP background, and know that the bandwidth on an ethernet port is certainly capable of accepting way more than 100 ports of audio.

So my question is.. Is there a small module I can purchase that will take an analogue signal and convert it to UDP and some sort of codec, and forward it on as network packets?

Is there anything you can suggest reading that may help?

Comment: Yes, one such module is called an ADC! No matter what your solution, you will need an ADC to do this conversion. What kind of bandwidth does the audio use? Do you need this to work in real time?

Comment: You're really going to have to be more specific about the nature of the "analog audio" that you're dealing with, given that the VoIP gear you're already familiar with is (apparently) unsuitable.

Comment: What kind of audio? What is acceptable channel-to-channel latency and overall latency? What is the quality level you need? 100 channels of 192kHz pro-quality music audio has very different requirements from 100 channels of 8kHz VoIP traffic.

Answer (score 4):

You know that shopping questions are not allowed here?  Fortunately, I have never been one to follow the rules...

Large amounts of audio over Ethernet is not easy-- or cheap.  I've been doing this professionally for the past 14 years, and I still have not gotten the price down to what I would consider cheap.

I would not recommend a DIY approach to this.  Building the PCB's, writing the software, testing, etc. is difficult for this type of project.  That's fine if you want to start a new career in audio over Ethernet, but this is probably too much for someone who just does this as a hobby.

For commercial products, the cheapest that I know of are the boxes by [Atterotech](http://www.atterotech.com/).  They follow the Cobranet protocol standard and so will inter-operate with other Cobranet devices.  But while I said this is the cheapest, it is not cheap!  Also, this is pro-audio gear, with pro-audio performance.   Other companies that make similar products are [QSC Audio](http://www.qscaudio.com/), [Rane](http://www.rane.com/), [Whirlwind](http://whirlwindusa.com/catalog/digital-audio-networking), Peavey, Biamp, and many others.

There is not much for modules that does both the networking interface and the ADC/DAC circuits.  In a former life I designed the Cirrus Logic [CM-1](http://www.cirrus.com/en/products/cm-1.html) and [CM-2](http://www.cirrus.com/en/products/cm-2.html) modules which will do up to 32x32 channels of networked audio-- but they do not include the ADC's and DAC's.  Connecting converters to these modules is not difficult, but might still be beyond what you want to do.

There are other modules similar to the CM-1/2 from [Audinate](http://www.audinate.com/), Lab X, and others.  But I do not think that these will be any easier or cheaper for your uses.

Comment: +1 for not following that particular rule. Shopping is a key part of solving electronics problems, and the "no shopping" rule reeks of elitism and ivory tower theoreticians.

Comment: I think the "no shopping" rule is more for "where can I find a device to do x" type questions. I didn't consider this, nor your answer, shopping.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so without knowing much about your application, I'll just comment more generally about my experience with audio over IP.

You didn't mention any kind of real-time requirements - if all you need to do is record a bunch of audio for later playback, ignore the following.

Again, you didn't mention audio bandwidth - choice of solution will be very influenced by this.

So my experience is mostly with RTP - it's a good bet for a protocol, sits neatly on UDP and there is lots of open source tools etc.  It also supports broadcast use of IP; so a virtual "cross patch panel" is doable.

You need to think about latency of your streams, and generally about how concerned you are with *synchronising* playback of 10, 20, 50 streams etc.

Latency is incurred all through the chain - encode, transport, decode.

Some codecs have a minimum latency; some are engineered for low latency.
**All** audio codecs make a tradeoff between quality, latency and CPU effort.

Most low latency codecs generate pretty short packets, so your network efficiency drops a little (lots of short packets means lots of IP overhead).

Also keep in mind that the chattiness of all that audio (while doable) is problematic for Ethernet due to the way it's designed.  Just dividing your network bandwidth by your audio data rate is *not* a good way to do it.

I don't have any suggestions for hardware, but in theory you could do several channels of audio on anything from an Arduino Mega up...

Comment: Keep in mind that many/most of the low-latency audio over Ethernet protocols do not use a CODEC at all, they just pass straight PCM data.  Short packets is something to be concerned about, but 100 channels isn't a lot of data for Gigabit Ethernet (and too much for 100 MBit Ethernet, assuming 24 bit/48 KHz/PCM data).  Also, depending on the network audio topology, several channels can be put into the same Ethernet packet in order to avoid small packets and the resulting high overhead.

Comment: Very much agree on your point about topology.
Personally I lump PCM with "codecs" (maybe "the mother of all codecs") given that there's at least four flavours of PCM that have RTP profiles (mu-Law, A-Law, Linear, ADPCM) that I can think of  (off the top of my head).